# php 2 file input fields

Tags: php

I have got a form that has 2 file input fields in it but it only uploads one of the files (the first one "u_img") from the input field. bellow are the input fields

```
<input name="u_img" type="file" />
<input name="u_upload" type="file" />
```

im using this php to upload it.

```
$pic_upload_path = "/home/users/A006193/fgpostbus.nl/www.fgpostbus.nl/enquete/";

// foto 1
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['u_upload']['tmp_name']))
{
$pic_loc_1 = $pic_upload_path.md5(time()).'_'.$_FILES['u_upload']['name'];
$rel_pic_loc_1 = "enquete/";
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['u_upload']['tmp_name'],$pic_loc_1))
    {
    //echo "Het bestand is verplaatst naar $pic_loc1!";
    }
$rel_pic_loc_1 .= "".md5(time()).'_'.$_FILES['u_upload']['name']."";
}

if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['u_img']['tmp_name']))
{
$pic_loc_2 = $pic_upload_path.md5(time()).'_'.$_FILES['u_img']['name'];
$rel_pic_loc_2 = "enquete/";
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['u_img']['tmp_name'],$pic_loc_2))
    {
    //echo "Het bestand is verplaatst naar $pic_loc2!";
    }
$rel_pic_loc_2 .= "".md5(time()).'_'.$_FILES['u_img']['name']."";
}
```

i been looking at this for ages and i cant see why it doesnt work.

added:

result from print_r($_FILES);

```
Array
(
[u_img] => Array
    (
        [name] => natasha.jpg
        [type] => image/jpeg
        [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpXU56Pg
        [error] => 0
        [size] => 5414
    )

[u_upload] => Array
    (
        [name] => DSC_0003.jpg
        [type] => image/jpeg
        [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpb4vAZj
        [error] => 0
        [size] => 110476
    )

)
```

Comment: Have you tried print_r($_FILES) after upload?

Comment: also as a pointer, `time()` might change between the `$pic_loc_1` and `$rel_pic_loc_1` lines, so in this instance your `$rel_pic_loc_1` will be wrong. Call it once, assign to a varaible and use that.

Comment: Do you have <form> and </form> twice (around each input) or just once (around both inputs)? That would account for it. You need it once, around both inputs.

Comment: i have added the print_r($_FILES) result Robbie i have to send both the inputs on one submit, wont putting 2 form tags around them send them individually?

Comment: Have u checked max_upload_size ? try uploading two different small files.

Comment: maybe you can use foreach instead of having 2 if statement.

Comment: as far as I remember, you can try to indicate the same tag-name for both inputs and access files on the server like $_FILES['tag_name'][0], $_FILES['tag_name'][1]... and yes, like it was said earlier, check the max file size as a php-option.